# Is energy consumption of the 3kw kettle lower than 2kw kettle?

Tags: heat, efficiency, water, cost

On the market there are 2kw 1.7 liter kettles and also 3kw 1.7 liter kettles.

I understand that bringing the same quantity of water to the same temperature require same amount of energy, but from the engineering perspective could it be that one or the other have better efficiency etc.

Comment: It is about comfort, efficiency may be slightly different, but many over factors has bigger effect 
on it. like body from plastic or metall

Comment: Typically, the efficiency of electric heaters is very, very close to each other (and very high). It is doubtful that there will be any more than a very small difference between your 2kW and 3kW kettles. NOTE: when I say that the efficiency is high, I am only considering the conversion efficiency of electricity into heat. Of course, if your electricity comes from burning fuel, well, it would be more efficient to heat your water by burning fuel and avoid the conversion from heat to electricity then back to heat. The efficiency of converting heat to electricity is pretty low. See, "Carnot cycle."

Comment: I doubt there's a lot of difference. Probably depends on construction of the heater and so on. If coupling to the water was perfect the 3kW kettle would use slightly less energy since it spends less time in the heating phase, but I have serious doubts that translates to reality. Electric heaters are 100% (in)efficient but there are other factors.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, heating the water faster means greater IsquareR loss in supply wiring. On the other hand, heating it more slowly allows greater time for heat to transfer from kettle to surroundings. Etc. There are a bunch of small second order effects.

Comment: Which country is this? Or rather, what mains voltage you have, and what is the fuse ratings? A 3kW heater would in theory just boil the water in slightly less time than a 2kW heater, but it would also need fuses rated 13A or above.

Comment: @mkeith Agreed. I must say, for convenience, I prefer the mighty 3kW European kettles over the slow and wimpy 1.5kW ones that we 120V folks have to live with.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes. I wish we used 240 for everything instead of 120. It doesn't seem like the hazard level is much different so might as well have lower copper losses or smaller wires.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The 3kW might be a UK thing due to their ring wiring that allows for ridiculous currents. I can only get 2400W ones in shops, as they still allow for 10A breakers. 16A could be in use when expecting higher load such as kitchen sockets.

Comment: So considerably higher current cause bigger drop voltage on wires from source to load, bigger energy loss and as result lower efficiency.

Comment: @user263983 yes that is one effect. However, that will be a small effect since the wire is sized for the purpose. Also, there are other effects which may act to make the 3kW version more efficient. Knowing which of all these effects is most significant is quite difficult. So unless careful and precise measurements are done, I don't think anyone can say with certainty which is more efficient.

Comment: @mkeith I just gave an example. Where is so many things which can affect efficiency, includes humidity, ambient temperature, etc. Some of factors may be random and what calculations or measurements does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All electric heaters are 100% efficient, at the terminals to its direct environment.

There will however be differences in losses, due to heating things that are not part of the payload.

- The 2 kW kettle, with its lower supply current, will cause roughly half the I<sup>2</sup>R losses in the supply wiring than the 3 kW kettle.
- The 3 kW kettle will take less time to boil a certain amount of water. Kettles are not typically insulated, the surface convection losses to the air can be quite high, possibly several hundred watts, so the 3 kW kettle loses less energy to the environment while heating.

That's not the end of the story however, as the two types of kettle will not necessarily be used in the same way, there are psychological factors to consider.

- As a 2 kW kettle takes a long time to boil (especially if you used to own a 3 kW version), the user might be more keen to fill it with only the right amount of water. A 3 kW owner might be more careless and overfill it, as they don't suffer so much heating time penalty. This excess water causes two losses. It takes extra energy to heat, which is lost if the kettle cools down between uses. By lengthening the boiling time, it increases the losses to ambient during boiling.

Answer (score 0):

if you had a 5W kettle it oudl probably noy produce heat fast enough to counter heat loss to the environment so it would be infinitely inefficient

Somewhere between 5W and 1KW there is enough power to boil water.

And the faster it is boiled the less time there is for heat to be lost

all else being equal the 3KW heater would have less than two thirds of the inefficiency of the 2KW heater.

But resistive heating is very efficient to start with:

so if the 2KW is 97% efficient the 3KW would be 98% efficient

Comment: A 5W kettle inside of a *really good* insulating blanket?  You just need to be patient waiting for your tea...